# TypeScript generic contraints with extending and default parameters

Tags: typescript, generics, default-value

So I am trying to write a function which has a generic which extends a certain object thus constrains it. Next I would like to use this generic together with a definition of a parameter to generate a new "enhanced" parameter. 
This is all good but as soon as I want to introduce a default value to the parameter TypeScript complains with a message as follow (Some different variations of this in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20test1%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%3E(options%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20''%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(options)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test2%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20foo%3F%3A%20string%20%7D%3E(options%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7B%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(options)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test3%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(options%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Bbar%3A%20false%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(options)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test4%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20%7Bbar%3F%3A%20boolean%7D%3E(options%3A%20T%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Bbar%3A%20false%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(options)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20test5%20%3D%20(options%3A%20%7Bfoo%3F%3A%20string%7D%20%26%20%7B%20bar%3F%3A%20boolean%20%7D%20%3D%20%7Bbar%3A%20false%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(options)%3B%0D%0A%7D)):

Function:

```
const test1 = <T extends { foo?: string }>(options: T & { bar?: boolean } = {foo: 
''}) => {
    console.log(options);
}
```

The error:

> Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T & { bar?:
>   boolean; }'.
>         Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'foo' does not exist in type 'T & { bar?: boolean; }'. Did you mean to write
>   'foo'?

The compiler warns me that I probably wanted to use foo, which I actually did. Is it simply not possible to use a generic in this way or is this a bug in TypeScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type `T` at the definition time is unknown, so the compiler throws this error that you cannot initialize something you are unaware of. There are a couple of workarounds I can think of, but not sure how useful they are for your case.

You can leave type `T` as is, and use union types for the `options` parameter as follows:

```
const test1 = <T> (options: T | { bar?: boolean } | { foo?: string } = { foo: '' }) => {
  console.log(options);
};
```

Another workaround is to use a type assertion and manually tell the compiler that the initializer is of the type it needs to be:

```
const test2 = <T extends { foo?: string }>(options: T & { bar?: boolean } = { foo: '' } as T & { bar?: boolean }) => {
  console.log(options);
};
```

But keep in mind that these are just workarounds and whenever you have to use a workaround, it implies a flaw in the design. Maybe you can take a second look at your logic and improve it in order to remove the need for these workarounds. Or maybe, you can skip argument initialization and add `options.foo = options.foo || '';` as the first line of code in your function. Just some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why none of the initializations work is that you can't initialize something you don't know. Consider the following call:

```
test1<{ foo: string, goo: boolean}>();
```

The generic parameter is valid for the function, but it has an extra property, `goo`, which is mandatory, but unspecified in your default value for options. This is why the compiler complains about the assignment, you don't know the final shape of  `T`, you only know the minimum requirements for it, so you can't build an object that will be compatible with`T`

If you are ok with `options` not having all mandatory properties specified on the generic type parameter, you can use a type assertion

```
const test1 = <T extends { foo?: string }>(options: T & { bar?: boolean } = <any>{foo: ''}) => {
    console.log(options);
}
```